# Django create Scheduling

Tags: python, django

Hi, I run a app of Django, and I want that it run in a specific time (for example: form 9 am to 0 pm).

One sol can be (in view.py):

I can verify the hour and if it is not beteween this hours can redirect to a specifict page.

There is a other form?

Comment: So you want something to happen on a clients machine at a specific time? or you want to get the servers time and redirect the *server* to a page at a specific time? What have you tried?

Comment: The perfect solution is than in a specific time the service turn off, and the other time sich on, but it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not connected to the django / python and I think this is more likely OS specific question, so my suggestion would be to use cron:

```
0 9 * * * __user__ /abs/path/to/service start
59 23 * * * __user__ /abs/path/to/service stop
```

cron job timing format is following:

```
minute | hour | day | month | day of week | user | command

0        9      *     *       *             (1)    (2)
```

59       23     *     *       *             (1)    (2)

writing only minutes and hours, means that this job should run everyday. for user section (1) it indicates which user runs the command and for command section (2), this is the indicator what command should be run

hope this helps